# How to filter a listview?

Tags: java, android

I have a list view and i want to show records by filter suppose i have an array list called expenseList. in expenseList i am able to filter single item like this

```
 if (!dealerexpautoa.getText().toString().equals("")){
                        ArrayList<ExpenseStatusModel.Expense> expensetypeList= new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < expenseList.size(); i++)
                        {
                            if (expenseList.get(i).getDealerName().equalsIgnoreCase(dealerexpautoa.getText().toString())) {

                                expensetypeList.add(expenseList.get(i));
                            }
                        }
                        adapterExpenseView.filterList(expensetypeList);

                    }
```

here getting the perfect output but when i need to perform same task with two string then it is not getting me the right out put

i have an EditText and Spinner i want to compare both and print in list view

```
else if(!spn.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Select Type")
                            && !dealerexpautoa.getText().toString().equals("")){
                        ArrayList<ExpenseStatusModel.Expense> expensetypeList= new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < expenseList.size(); i++)
                        {
                            if (expenseList.get(i).getDealerName().equalsIgnoreCase(dealerexpautoa.getText().toString()) &&
                                    expenseList.get(i).getExpenseType().equalsIgnoreCase(spn.getSelectedItem().toString())) {

                                expensetypeList.add(expenseList.get(i));
                            }
                        }
                        adapterExpenseView.filterList(expensetypeList);

                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition expression in `if` branch is:

```
!dealerexpautoa.getText().toString().equals("")
```

and the condition expression in `else` branch is

```
!spn.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Select Type")
                            && !dealerexpautoa.getText().toString().equals("")
```

this two expressions are not mutually exclusive, only dealerexpautoa text is equal empty string, it could enter into `else` branch, but in `else` branch,the condition needs dealerexpautoa text not equal empty string, so this is contradictory.

Comment: so how to perform this task any example? i know that only first condition is checked by if... but the thing is i  show this code for how i tried

Comment: unclear total login, try using two independent if clause, no else branch.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to write if in your else statement

```
else if(!spn.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Select Type")
                            && !dealerexpautoa.getText().toString().equals("")){
                        ArrayList<ExpenseStatusModel.Expense> expensetypeList= new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < expenseList.size(); i++)
                        {
                            if (expenseList.get(i).getDealerName().equalsIgnoreCase(dealerexpautoa.getText().toString()) &&
                                    expenseList.get(i).getExpenseType().equalsIgnoreCase(spn.getSelectedItem().toString())) {

                                expensetypeList.add(expenseList.get(i));
                            }
                        }
                        adapterExpenseView.filterList(expensetypeList);

                    }
```

Comment: i am sorry i forgot to write if in the question but actually in my project it is else if only